# How do I throttle a command in a terminal window?

Tags: cpu-load, memory-usage, image-processing

I needed to run `convert` with a lot of images at the same time. The command took quite a while but this doesn't bother me.

The issue is that this command rendered my computer unusable while the command was running (for about 15 minutes).

So is it possible to throttle the command by limiting resources (processor and memory) to the command, directly from the command line? This can only work if I add something **to the same line** before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> because once I start the process the computer slows so much that it is impossible for example to switch to "System monitor" and reduce priority.

### Edit: top and iotop results

I managed to run `top` and `sudo iotop >iotop.txt` while doing one of these convert operations. (The iotop.txt file produced is difficult to read)

Results of top:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
14275 username     20   0 4043m 3.0g 1448 D   7.0 80.4   0:16.45 convert
```

Results of iotop:

```
[?1049h[1;24r(B[m[4l[?7h[?1h=[39;49m[?25l[39;49m(B[m[H[2JTotal DISK READ:    1269.04 K/s | Total DISK WRITE:[59G0.00 B/s
(B[0;7m  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN(B[0;1;7m     IO>(B[0;7m    COMMAND          [3;2H(B[m2516 be/4 username     350.08 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % zeitgeist-datahub
 7394 be/4 username     568.88 K/s    0.00 B/s 77.41 %  0.00 % --rendere~.530483991[5;1H14275 idle username     350.08 K/s    0.00 B/s 37.49 %  0.00 % convert S~f test.pdf[6;2H2048 be/4 root[6;24H0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/3:2]
[5G1 be/4 root[7;24H0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
```

Furthermore, even after the process ends, the computer does not return to the previous performance. I found a way around this by running `sudo swapoff -a` followed by `sudo swapon -a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, boy, I just caught this... quoting OP:

> Furthermore, even after the process ends, the computer does not return to the previous performance. I found a way around this by running `sudo swapoff -a` followed by `sudo swapon -a`

OK, so that means you were exhausting the available RAM on your system, which means you're just plain trying to run too many `convert` processes at once.  We'd need to look at your actual syntax in spawning `convert` to advise, but basically, you need to make sure you don't try to open more simultaneous processes than you have the RAM to comfortably handle.

Since you state what's causing this is `convert *.tif blah.pdf`, what's happening is that the content of every single TIF and its conversion to PDF are getting stuffed into RAM at once.  What you need to do is split the job up so that this isn't necessary.  One possibility that leaps to mind is instead doing something like `find . -iname '*.tif' | xargs -I% convert % %.pdf`, then using `pdftk` or something like it to glue all the individual pdfs together.  If you *really* want to get fancy, and you have a multicore CPU, this also affords you the chance to write a small script to run conversions in batches of *n*, where *n* is your number of cores, and get the whole thing done significantly faster. :)

pdftk how-to: http://ubuntuhowtos.com/howtos/merge_pdf_files  (basically boils down to `sudo apt-get install pdftk; pdftk *.pdf cat output merged.pdf`)

Comment: I'm just running ONE `convert *.tif bla.pdf` process at a time, but the input is a whole bunch of tif images. It's a way to produce one pdf from a bunch of images that works well but stifles my pc.

Comment: ^^ see edited answer please :)

Comment: This worked perfectly with one simple modification. `find . -iname '*.tif' | xargs -I% convert % %.pdf` instead of `find . -iname '*.pdf' | xargs -I% convert % %.pdf`. It was quicker too! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, malfunction between brain and fingers :-)

Comment: One small modification… It is a good thing to know about the `-exec` and `-execdir` options for `find`. In your case, instead of using `xargs`, I would use: `find -iname '*.tif' -execdir convert {} {}.pdf ';'`

Answer (score 12):

`man nice`, and if you need I/O throttling `man ionice`.

Let's look at some simple examples.

**Throttling CPU usage:**

```
you@box:/$ nice -n 10 /usr/bin/convert blah.gif blah.jpg
```

From your description, however, CPU usage is almost certainly not your real problem here.  More likely, you're having severe I/O contention.

**Throttling Disk Usage:**

```
you@box:/$ ionice -c2 -n7 /usr/bin/convert blah.gif blah.jpg
```

`-c2` is "best effort", and `-n7` is the lowest "best effort" priority.  So, this will throttle the job to lower I/O priority than most other things on the system.

```
you@box:/$ ionice -c3 /usr/bin/convert blah.gif blah.jpg
```

`-c3` (no priority level necessary) means "Idle only".  Jobs set to `-c3` ONLY take up otherwise idle disk scheduling time, for virtually no impact at all on the system - but potentially a *considerably* longer execution time for your job, depending on how busy the rest of the system gets.

Comment: How would I integrate `nice` in a convert command? If I'm not going  wrong, nice works for already running processes.

Comment: See above... Also, srsly, read man page. It's a very easy man page, not chewy at all. :-)

Comment: I tried it. Sort of helped but not enough. I'll try `nice -n 20` next time.

Comment: Honestly I'm not too sure that CPU load is your problem here.  Have you tried doing `iotop` while running the process?  Usually a single process consuming lots of CPU will have very little effect on the usability of the system, but a process thrashing the hard drive can VERY quickly bring everything to a screeching halt - especially if you are using a conventional drive, not an SSD.

Comment: Since the whole system goes pretty unusable for you, you might try something along the lines of `convert blah.gif blah.jpg & iotop` so that `iotop` will fire up instantly as soon as you've started your `convert` job.

Comment: I read `man ionice` but it's quite enigmatic to me. Would `ionice -c 3 convert *.gif bla.pdf` do the trick or should I try `-c 2 -n 7`?

Comment: Depends on how aggressive you want to be.  ionice -c3 means that the convert will only happen when the disk is absolutely IDLE, so it definitely leaves the system usable, but it might take longer to do your job than you would like.  ionice -c2 -n7 will be willing to impact the rest of the system some, but will still have the convert job at a lower priority than pretty much everything else.  So it's your call.

Comment: I tried both and the system is rendered unusable with either.

Comment: we'll need to see output from both `top` and `iotop` before advising further, then.

Comment: What about `ulimit` ?

Comment: ulimit is irrelevant.  see second answer just posted.  the stuff in this answer is very useful so I don't want to mess with it, but **your** actual problem is entirely different, which I did not realize until I saw the workaround you'd edited into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty good article on using a program called `cpulimit` to limit the cpu usage of any process:

http://maketecheasier.com/limit-cpu-usage-of-any-process-in-linux/2010/09/22

The problem is like you said finding the PID of the `convert` process after it has started.

After starting `convert` if you can still type commands in the terminal you can run `ps aux | grep convert` to find it's PID, then `sudo cpulimit -p PID -l CPU%` to start throttling.

Or if starting `convert` also locks up your terminal the article shows you how you can run `cpulimit` as a background daemon that will automatically monitor and throttle any processes over a certain amount of CPU usage.  Good luck!

Comment: This script is a bad idea, and primitive compared to the built-in `nice` command.  `cpulimit` will limit the process to a certain % CPU usage whether or not anything else needs the CPU time; `nice`, by contrast, sets priority levels (40 total!) which allow prioritization of one task above (or below) others.